# How to add inline PHP to a .twig file?

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to modify the `<body>` tag in a .twig file.

The body tag looks like this...

`<body{{ body_id is not empty ? ' id=' ~ body_id }} >`

...and I want to add...

`class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php');  ?>-page"`

But when I do so I end up with this mess:

`<body id="foo" class="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php');  ?>-page">`

In short, how can I add inline PHP to a .twig file?

Comment: It is twig purpose to not do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig won't interpret PHP - it doesn't understand what it means.

A better way of doing this is to pass the result of `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php'` into the twig context from whatever PHP script you call the template.

Assuming you call the context var `body_classes` you can then update the template to something like this:

```
<body{{ body_id is not empty ? ' id=' ~ body_id }}{{ body_classes is not empty ? ' class=' ~ body_classes }} >
```

Edit: While this approach may seem counterintuitive at first it gives you the benefit of separating logic and presentation.

Comment: I'd remove the extra space in between `...body_id }} {{ body_class...` as you are adding the space with `' class=...`

Comment: I realize now that I am out of my depth with this, so I will look at a different solution. But I appreciate the answer.